# Issues in using Kubernetes Java client library in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, kubernetes, okhttp, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to use [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) java client library for Kubernetes from app engine. But I ran into issues because this client library uses `okhttp` client which doesn't work in app engine as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912029/using-okhttp-client-via-okclient-on-google-app-engine-throws-a-java-lang-noclas).

The error described in the previous SO link is the exact error I am getting on app engine. 
As per this [link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/343), `okhttp` exposes the method which can be over-ridden such that this issue isn't seen. There is actually a library for this [here](https://github.com/apkelly/GoogleAppEngineOkHttp). But the issue is that the `OkHttpClient` has been moved from package `com.squareup.okhttp` to `okhttp3` from version 3.x onwards in which the changes that I require are present. This old version of `okhttp` is used in the Kubernetes client library and shows error if I try to set the new okhttp.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Or are there any other client libraries which can be used from app engine. I know of client from [fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) but it has support only till kubernetes version 1.7.10 as of now. I still haven't tried it on app engine though.

Edit:

Even the fabric8 client has the same issue in app engine. It is trying to get the `ProxySelector` which is not a whitelisted class in appengine.

Comment: Maybe you could try the Java 8 runtime, where you can use all the standard Java library unlike the Java 7 runtime. After all, the Java 7 runtime is now deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime

Comment: @ChanseokOh Thank you. It works with Java 8 runtime.  Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try the Java 8 runtime where you can use all the standard Java library, unlike the Java 7 runtime which allows only select whitelisted JRE classes. After all, the Java 7 runtime is now deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime

However, do note that there are some differences, so you may want to take a look at the migration guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8